# SOQL: Expression as Column?

Tags: soql

I need all accounts modified in a specific period:

```
SELECT id FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate >= $t0 AND LastModifiedDate <= $t1
```

Additionally, I need to know whether it was modified by a specific user or not.
Can I add a boolean column to my query result which is true if LastModifiedById = $myUserId ? Something like:

```
SELECT id, (IF LastModifiedById = 'userId' THEN true ELSE false) FROM ...
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get records modified in spesific time period by certain user then you need to change your SOQL like this;

```
SELECT id FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate >= $t0 AND LastModifiedDate <= $t1 AND LastModifiedById = :userId
```

But if you need to get records modified in spesific time period and check if record was modified ***by certain user or not*** then you need to use a formula field to determine if the record was modified in certain time period by spesific user.